# Where to get CumulusCI Jenkins Configuration Zip

Tags: jenkins, ci

I am currently struggling to get a CI process setup on Jenkins using Cumulus CI.
Does anybody know where I can get an export of someone's Jenkins Configuration? I have tried searching, but so far I cannot find anything.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend starting with the CumulusCIJenkins project which I created last year to make setting up Jenkins for CumulusCI easy.  CumulusCIJenkins requires a newish Linux server (the instructions are for Ubuntu LTS 14) and uses Docker to build a Jenkins site with all the necessary plugins and jenkins-job-builder to help configure the jobs for your project.  We're in the process of switching our manually built Jenkins instance to CumulusCIJenkins.

The full installation instructions can be found in the repository's README file:
https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/CumulusCIJenkins

Please let me know (or feel free to contribute) any changes you think might make the README more clear for others.

Comment: Hey @Jason - slightly off topic, but seriously thank you for your work (and everyone else that has contributed).

Comment: Thanks.  Honestly, the coolest part is learning that there are people out there using that that I've never had any contact with.  It's great to hear :)

Comment: Thanks @JasonLantz too! I have been trying for sometime to get CumulusCI working on Bamboo, I now have the basic deploy process working, but I need to do some work with cinamon to get tests and results working in Bamboo.

Comment: The CumulusCIJenkins git project has moved [here](https://github.com/joeyweaver/CumulusCIJenkins) ... @Jason you may want to update your answer to point to the new link.